# Change the location of an arrow by pressing ENTER key

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh

I am working on a C# project and I want to change the location of an arrow by pressing ENTER key with different size of iteration for different comboBox selections. Actually it works but the problem is that I can not refresh the Form before changing comboBox Selection. I want to see iteration step by step but it moves if I change the comboBox selection. Here is the code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {

                this.BackColor = Color.Black;
                label1.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
                label1.Text = "Environment is Space";
                pictureBox2.Image = list.Images[4];
                t = 100; // iteration amount

            }

            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;
                label1.Text = "Environment is Water";
                pictureBox2.Image = list.Images[3];
                t = 50; // iteration amount

            }

            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod;
                label1.ForeColor = Color.Firebrick;
                label1.Text = "Environment is Honey";
                pictureBox2.Image = list.Images[2];
                t = 20; // iteration amount
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            // Drawing arrow
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255), 8);
            pen.StartCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
            pen.EndCap = LineCap.RoundAnchor;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, x+50, 200, x, 200);

        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // pressed Enter => change x
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (x < y)
                {
                    x += t;

                }
            }
        }
```

To be more clear:
I want like:              Click-> Enter + Move-> Arrow + Click->Enter + Move -> Arrow
Now it works like:        Click-> Enter + Change-> comboBox + Move->Arrow

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An array is a logical data structure, I am not sure how you would move one. Can you provide a complete compilable example as your description is not very clear.

Comment: I planned to write an arrow instead of an array, sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a timer solution?

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { 
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { comboBox1.SelectedIndex = (comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % comboBox1.Items.Count; });
        };
        timer.Start();
```

It's hard to understand what do you mean.

Comment: No, I want to see the change step by step. I do not want to see the whole change after I change the comboBox selection. All I want is to see Click-> Enter + Move-> Arrow + Click->Enter + Move -> Arrow. However, it flows like Click-> Enter + Change-> comboBox + Move->Arrow right now.